# installing bcrypt-ruby (rails 3.2.8 using devise) on a raspberry pi

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, raspberry-pi, bcrypt-ruby

I'm having fun trying to get my raspberry pi setup as a staging server.  It's a rails app 3.2.8 using devise for authentication.

When it's bundling the install is failing with

```
Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
```

If I "sudo gem install  bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1' " then it installs fine, but the capistrano deploy is always failing.

Any ideas?  I'd rather not deploy as sudo as that's not how it works in production.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have a working ruby development library installed. Check your Ruby version:

```
$ ruby --version
```

Assuming that you have ruby v1.9.3, install `ruby1.9.3-dev`. The version number doesn't matter; just use the same version number that you have installed.

Comment: I was stumped by this answer as in developing Rails apps, I never had a special "dev" version of ruby. Following your lead, I see on the ruby.org site that you can on the pi run this: sudo apt-get install ruby-full and that got me past this error, thx.